# How To Make This Tire Loop?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]
[image]
[image]

The Tire is model like that,
How to eliminate the gap and make this tire threat Loop full circle
*The gap is mark with a red X

I have tried using "Circle" modifier but the results were chaotic and didnt make any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how you created your tire, because I only see that your *Array* modifier is set to a count of 5. In one screenshot you have evenly spaced segments with an angle of 72° between them, but the segments are too small to connect to each other... in the other screenshot they are not evenly spaced and are connected, but again the segments are too small to close the gap.

I can only tell you how I would create a tire: first of all, the amount of preparation depends on if I want to make everything just eyeballing or I know beforehand, how many times my segment should be repeated and what the final diameter of the finished tire should be. The orientation of the base segment depends on the way I want the tire to be oriented in the viewport.

So let's start with the more complicated stuff, specific predefined values, because the eyeballing version is simply doing the same without calculations ;)

The desired outcome in this example: a segment repeated 10× around, the outer diameter at the end should be 60 cm i.e 0.6 m in total. A diameter of 0.6 means, the circumference would be

$$0.6\cdot\pi\approx 1.885$$

so with 10 segments this means a length of

$$\frac{1.885}{10}=0.1885$$

for the base segment.

For the orientation I want the finished tire to be constructed so that I watch it from the side when in *Right Orthographic* view (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>), so the schematics look something like this:

[image: tire schematics]

Now to get these parameters correct I build the base segment like this: no curvature, starting at the origin point with a +Z height of the calculated length of 0.1885 m and the tread at the origin, the rest of the tire going in +Y direction (I'm going to construct a realistic tire here, this is just to see the orientation):

[image: base segment profile]

With the base segment in the correct size and orientation, I add an *Array* modifier to duplicate the segments. Since the segment is built vertical, the array has to be set to a *relative Offset* of 1 on the Z axis. After setting the *Count* to the desired amount of 10, the height changed from 0.189 to the needed circumference length of 1.89 m (actually from 0.1885 to 1.885, but Blender only shows three relevant digits):

[image: array modifier]

And then there is only one thing left to do: add a *Simple Deform* modifier with the correct settings. In this case these are using *Bend* with an *Angle* of 360° (of course when you want a full circle) and the *Axis* has to be X. And now you have a tire with a diameter of 0.6 m as you can see from the dimensions in the viewport:

[image: simple deform modifier]

The simpler way if you do not need precise measurements is simply doing this all *Pi × thumb* as we say in German. By the way, changing the number of segments in the array now will not change the full circle by leaving a gap or overlapping, it will only change the diameter of the resulting circle.

A tip if you want to create different tires with different profiles which might even vary in tread depth etc. (I'm sorry, I don't even know the right words in tire technology) but they should all fit to a given rim diameter, then instead of calcuationg the total circumference overall, calculate the rim circumference and use this as height for the base segment. Then you only have shift the profile on the Y axis so that the part where the tire meets the rim lies on the object origin. Then all tire profiles constructed like this will fit the wheel rim.

**Practical example of preparing a segment:** I apologize for my crappy low poly profiles... let's say I have a wheel rim with a diameter of 0.6 m (a little large, I just took the value from earlier on):

[image: wheel rim]

Then I want to construct three completely different tires, but they should all fit on the wheel rim. Of course I have to create them in the correct width (which should not be much of the problem), the interesting part is to get the height correct when you know how often a segment should be repeated:

[image: tire variations]

Like shown with formulas before, when you know the diameter of the rim, it is easy to get the circumference, divide it by the number of segments and you have the height for one segment. When I start off with a simple plane or cube, you can simply enter the formula in the field for the Z dimension and let Blender calculate the needed height, shown here for the left profile with the 16 segments. After changing the dimension, the scale is off. To avoid any issues later on, this should be reset to 1 by applying the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*.

[image: setting the dimension]

The segments have no curvature yet (make sure you have enough resolution for a smoother bending later) and everything is the same height. A tire has of course a shorter diameter towards the center than on the outside. So to make sure, the part where the tire sits inside the rim gets the correct diameter, you have to place the profile mesh with this part on the object's origin:

[image: mesh on origin]

After preparing the segments like this, the *Array* modifier just needs to be set on the correct *Count* number 16, 8 or 24 in these examples and then the *Simple Deform* automatically creates a tire in the correct size to fit the wheel rim:

[image: example tires]

**A few concluding side notes:** The bending is in +Y direction away from the origin, so the resulting ring is not centered on the origin. Which means, to have a wheel rim in the center of the tire, the rim has to be the distance of the radius away in +Y direction from the tire's origin (or the tire the radius distance in -Y direction). To have the tire move and rotate with the axis of the rim, it can be parented to the rim.

Some people use an empty for the *Simple Deform* modifier as *Origin* point. Although this can have advantages in some cases, here it would mean you have to place the mesh differently from the tire's origin and you have to parent the tire to the empty and then the empty to the rim - unnecessary additional relations.

About the mesh construction: I have placed the segment always with the bottom on the origin - but the vertical placement is not so important, since the *Relative Offset* of Z = 1 in the *Array* modifier always puts the duplicates on top of each other, no matter how far up or down they are.

And last but not least: to get a good result you should make sure that all duplicates of the *Array* are connected. Therefore you should enable the *Merge* option and in its submenu the *First and Last Copies* option. And because the *Simple Deform* comes after the *Array*, this merging has no effect on the beginning and end of the circle. The *Simple Deform* has no option for merging, so it can be good to put a *Weld* modifier at the end, especially if you are also going to use other modifiers like *Bevel* or *Subdivision Surface* on the tire.

Comment: About how I model the tire threat, I followed this tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxu06q1ZK_Q), he modeled the threat in the curve angle without laying them out on the plane surface, so things were more complicated and hard to follow. However, Thank you so much for your guidance. I didnt realise just how much math matters in modeling, I still have a lot to learn so thank you again for the detail answer, I will soak this knowledge up as much as I can.

Comment: @Chef_0f_J0EY_SH3rWay Well, it depends, 3D modeling in Blender is not always the same as CAD for example. While CAD is or was mostly for construction etc. where things often have to be precise, in 3D modeling you can do a lot of things like characters, landscapes etc. where no precise construction is needed. Even when people do more technical models, I very often see tutorials where they just eyeball things while I think, man it would have been so easy to it accurate with simply typing a number, or using snapping etc.

Comment: @Chef_0f_J0EY_SH3rWay The same goes for this wheel here: I tried to show a way how you can do this when trying to use specific values, but as I said in my answer, you can of course do it in the same way but much easier without precise values. You could just create a single segment in whatever way you like, make sure it has enough resolution to bend well (especially in direction of the bend) and deform it. Then change the array count until you like the size or width/diameter ratio etc. The main complicated part is figuring out the _Simple Deform_ setup because it is a bit unintuitive 