# Cylinder's shape changes completely upon bending using simple diffusion, can somebody help?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, vertices, transforms

I hope things are going good.

I am very new to blender, and I am facing a simple problem that I can't seem to fix. I have created and rotated a mesh cylinder by 90 degrees. Now, when I try to bend the cylinder by applying a simple diffusion modifier, it looks like this instead of looking evenly bent. Bear in mind that I applied the scale and rotation transformations before the bending process by using Ctrl+A; I have also brought the origin to geometry.

Any help would be highly appreciated; thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Do you mean _Simple Deform_   ? You can't bend edges, those are always straight between 2 vertices. You can only move vertices around to change the edge direction. So you have to subdivide your mesh along the axis of deformation, to bend it.

Comment: It's not easy to tell you what you have to do since I see no orientation of your model nor how you want it to be bend, the only thing I know is the _Simple Deform_ is not so "simple" and works a bit unintuitive. Maybe you can get an idea how to bend something in a certain direction by reading my answer here: [How to make this tire loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314532/how-to-make-this-tire-loop/314566#314566)

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the lack of clarification. Yes, it is Simple Deform, my bad. So here's what I did exactly. 1) I deployed a mesh cylinder. 2) I selected the top and bottom faces of the cylinder and added bevels to smooth out the sharp edges. 3) I used the scale tool to make the default cylinder longer. 4) I added extra vertices along the length of the cylinder (I added about 8 using ctrl+r). 4) I used the rotate tool to rotate along the x-axis and lay it flat like a log. 5) I used ctrl+a to apply the transformations. 6) I use the simple deform modifier and that image is the result.

Comment: I will try to redo the whole thing to find mistakes in my tracks. In the meantime, I would appreciate your valuable input.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks!